# Batch-Insert, Transaction-Inserts or both? Which is faster?

Tags: mysql, sql

Which is faster?

1. **Batch Insert**

   ```
   insert into table values (1,2), (3,4), (5,6),...  ;
   ```
2. **Transaction Insert**

   ```
   begin transaction;
    insert into table values (1,2);
    insert into table values (3,4);
    ...
   end transaction;
   ```
3. **Both**

   ```
   begin transaction;
    insert into table values (1,2), (3,4), (5,6),...  ;
   end transaction;
   ```

Are 1 and 2 equivalent?

Comment: These should all be pretty similar in performance.

Comment: the first one is faster

Comment: Benchmark for your situation.

Comment: I think the first solution is the fastest. 1 and 3 have a syntax error, the outer set of parentheses shouldn't be there.